# AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute '_feed_input_names'

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm following the [`tf.keras` tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras) with python 2.7.5 but `model.fit(data, labels, epochs=10, batch_size=32)` gives me the error message:

```
>>> model.fit(data, labels, epochs=10, batch_size=32,validation_data=    (val_data, val_labels))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/software/TensorFlow/1.8-GPU-py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/engine/training.py", line 1143, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "/software/TensorFlow/1.8-GPU-py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/engine/training.py", line 751, in _standardize_user_data
    feed_input_names = self._feed_input_names
AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute '_feed_input_names'
```

Can anyone point out what is wrong?

Comment: The types of errors I see when using `tf.keras` are very strange. I'd probably try to use the original keras.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue ,not sure why, I did not search about it but when I added this argumant 
 **input_shape=(height,width,channels)** to my first layer of network the error went away.

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(firstLayer(....., input_shape=(height,width,channels))
```

I hope it helps you too.