# TF 2.3 Concatenate error - AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute '_nested_outputs'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

`fusion_model = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([m1.output, m2.output])`

m1 and m2 are Model objects.

I'm concatenating the outputs of the two models and I'm getting the following error:

AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute '_nested_outputs'

This exact code used to work in TF 1.14. Any help? thanks

After experimenting with this example, it appears to crash on the statement `m2.output` (`m1.output` runs fine)

my M2 model is:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
rescaling_1 (Rescaling)      (None, 456, 456, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
efficientnetb5 (Functional)  (None, 15, 15, 2048)      28513527  
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling2d (Gl (None, 2048)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 160)               327840    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_19 (Dropout)         (None, 160)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
predictions (Dense)          (None, 19)                3059
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing a code snippet so we can reproduce the error?

Comment: @stephen_mugisha Hi I will work on that :)

Comment: @stephen_mugisha Hi can't provide a full example but this is the best I can provide for now :)

Comment: check this previous discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53758374/attributeerror-sequential-object-has-no-attribute-feed-input-names?rq=1) , it may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `build()` the model with the appropriate input_shape parameter. This is what's causing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error and was able to solved it by adding a `tf.keras.layers.InputLayer` at the beginning of my model.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/InputLayer