# How do I merge two keras model with no predefined input size

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I'm trying to merge the VGG16 model, LSTM model, and tensor input into one using concatenate layer

### LSTM Code

This is a simple LSTM model

```py
VOCAB_SIZE=1000
encoder = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.TextVectorization(max_tokens=VOCAB_SIZE)
encoder.adapt(np.array(df['caption']))

def build_lstm():
  model = Sequential(
      [
       encoder,
       Embedding(input_dim=len(encoder.get_vocabulary()), output_dim=64, mask_zero=True),
       Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64)),
       Dense(80, activation='relu'),
      ]
  )
  return model
```

### VGG16 Code

This is a VGG16 implementation in Keras

```py
def build_vgg16():
  model = Sequential(
      [
       Input(shape=(224,224,3)),
       Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),padding='same', activation='relu'),
       Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),padding='same', activation='relu'),
       MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)),
       Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'),
       Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'),
       MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)),
       Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'),
       Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'),
       Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'),
       MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)),
       Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'),
       Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'),
       Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'),
       MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)),
       Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'),
       Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'),
       Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'),
       MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)),
       Flatten(),
       Dense(512, activation='relu'),
       Dense(256, activation='relu'),
       Dense(128, activation='relu'),
       Dense(80, activation='relu'),
      ]
  )
  return model
```

### Linear Code

This model should merge the VGG16, LSTM, and a Tensor with 80 size

```py
def build_linear(classes, vgg16, lstm):
  input = Input(shape=(80))
  concat = Concatenate()([vgg16.output, lstm.output, input])
  linear = Flatten()(concat)
  linear = Dense(128, activation='relu')(linear)
  linear = Dense(64, activation='relu')(linear)
  linear = Dense(32, activation='relu')(linear)
  linear = Dense(classes, activation='softmax')(linear)
  return Model([vgg16.input, lstm.input, input], linear)
```

### Main Code

```py
vgg16 = build_vgg16()
lstm = build_lstm()

CLASSES = 6

linear = build_linear(CLASSES, vgg16, lstm)
```

But I got this error instead

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-291-0fbdec0644b4> in <module>()
      4 CLASSES = 6
      5 
----> 6 linear = build_linear(CLASSES, vgg16, lstm)

1 frames
<ipython-input-197-1bb0f30479b3> in build_linear(classes, vgg16, lstm)
      1 def build_linear(classes, vgg16, lstm):
      2   input = Input(shape=(80))
----> 3   concat = Concatenate()([vgg16.output, lstm.output, input])
      4   linear = Flatten()(concat)
      5   linear = Dense(128, activation='relu')(linear)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py in output(self)
    307       RuntimeError: if called in Eager mode.
    308     """
--> 309     return self._nested_outputs
    310 
    311   @property

AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute '_nested_outputs'
```

How can I merge this two model? The other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63783420/tf-2-3-concatenate-error-attributeerror-sequential-object-has-no-attribute) suggest to add Input layer but I don't quite understand to apply it in LSTM model

Comment: only a trial... what's happen if you remove lstm.output from the Concatenate layer?

Comment: As far as i know: LTSMs run on batches (sequencies) of the data, and thus predict on each entry of the batch => your lstm's output will be a list of batches' outputs. Depending on your problem, you should flatten this output (=> take each row's predict) or take only the last predict of the batch.

Comment: What is this "other question" you refer to?

Comment: @desertnaut I've added link to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63783420/tf-2-3-concatenate-error-attributeerror-sequential-object-has-no-attribute)

Comment: @MarcoCerliani it gave slightly different error
```<ipython-input-18-b1122262b60b> in build_linear(classes, vgg16, lstm)
      7   linear = Dense(32, activation='relu')(linear)
      8   linear = Dense(classes, activation='softmax')(linear)
----> 9   return Model([vgg16.input, lstm.input, input], linear)
```

Comment: @BintangPradana it works for me without problems :-)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem is in the encoder, it gives different length of output. The solution is to remove encoder from sequential model and give it predefined output sequence length, and add Input layer with shape of the encoder output length

### New LSTM Code

```
VOCAB_SIZE=1000
encoder = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.TextVectorization(max_tokens=VOCAB_SIZE, output_sequence_length=VOCAB_SIZE)
encoder.adapt(np.array(df['caption']))

def build_lstm():
  model = Sequential(
      [
       Input(shape=(len(encoder.get_vocabulary()))),
       Embedding(input_dim=len(encoder.get_vocabulary()), output_dim=64, mask_zero=True),
       Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64)),
       Dense(80, activation='relu'),
      ]
  )
  return model
```

Finally put the encoder in the training loop

### Training Loop Code

```
def train(epochs, model, dataset):
  for epoch in range(epochs):
    for step, (x, text, y) in enumerate(dataset):
      encoded = encoder(text)
      loss_val = train_step(x, y)
```

Comment: `output_sequence_length` is the time dimension and pads to that length. This should NOT be `VOCAB_SIZE` but instead length of sentence/sequence. Else you will produce 1000 length padded sequences.