# Keras: AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute '_nested_inputs'

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, tensor

**Overall Ask:**

Hi all, I am getting an attribute error and I am not quite sure what the cause is. I am following this [autoencoder tutorial](https://ekamperi.github.io/machine%20learning/2021/01/21/encoder-decoder-model.html) and trying to replicate some of the code. Can you tell me where I am going wrong?

**Autoencoder Build:**

```
# This is the dimension of the original space
input_dim = maxlen

# This is the dimension of the latent space (encoding space)
latent_dim = 2

encoder = Sequential([
    Dense(128, activation='relu', input_shape=(input_dim,)),
    Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    Dense(latent_dim, activation='relu')
])

decoder = Sequential([
    Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(latent_dim,)),
    Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    Dense(input_dim, activation=None)
])
```

When the encoder and decoder are connected in the following part, this is when the error arises:

```
autoencoder = Model(inputs=encoder.input, outputs=decoder(encoder.output))
```

**The error:**

```
AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute '_nested_inputs'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-55734003> in <module>
----> 1 autoencoder = Model(inputs=encoder.input, outputs=decoder(encoder.output))
      2 
      3 autoencoder.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py in input(self)
    241       AttributeError: If no inbound nodes are found.
    242     """
--> 243     return self._nested_inputs
    244 
    245   @property

AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute '_nested_inputs'
```

**What I tried:**

1. I googled the error, and a [post](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/14238) suggested altering the input shape. I do not know a lot about Autoencoders, but the architecture appears to already have this parameter.
2. Another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63783420/tf-2-3-concatenate-error-attributeerror-sequential-object-has-no-attribute) suggested adding input_shape (which is already there), and then using build()

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to combine your `encoder` and `dencoder` is to instantiate an `Input` layer and pass it through `encoder` and `decoder`.

```
inp = Input((input_dim,))
autoencoder = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=decoder(encoder(inp)))
autoencoder.compile('adam', 'mse')
```

[here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1aFr0DzGHhXmWqktETuYRBCb1RQpB_KUY?usp=sharing) is the running notebook